# Fastest/Proper way of ordering if/else if statements

Tags: php, benchmarking

In PHP, is there a fastest/proper way of ordering if/else if statements? For some reason, in my head, I like to think that the first if statement should be the anticipated "most popular" met condition, followed by the 2nd, etc. But, does it really matter? Is there is a speed or processing time affected if the 2nd condition is the most popular choice (meaning the system must always read the first condition)

Ex:

```
if ("This is the most chosen condition" == $conditions)
{

}
else if ("This is the second most chosen condition" == $conditions)
{

}
else if ("This is the third most chosen condition" == $conditions)
{

}
```

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)! :)

Comment: I would not consider it premature optimization if you had a complex operation that is evaluated in one of the if statements and a very simple operation. I would always check for the simple operation before invoking the complex operation.

Comment: what is, after some time, the third condition become the most popular? Or the body of the called function in the condition changes, and becames more complex operation?

Comment: if you are only compare on `$conditions`, `SWITCH` should be better -- `The switch statement is similar to a series of IF statements on the same expression. In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and execute a different piece of code depending on which value it equals to. This is exactly what the switch statement is for`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speedwise, it won't make a difference... Not a noticeable one... The order does count (it's sensibly faster putting the most used condition first), however it doesn't count for much. Choose the order which provides the best readability to those modifying and maintaining your code. They'll thank you later.

EDIT:
Also, consider this:

My function will return with a 25% chance.
I prefer writing:

```
if ( $chance25 )
    return;
else if ( $chance40 )
    doSomething();
else if ( $chance30 )
    doSomethingElse();
else if ( $chance5 )
    doSomethingElse2();
```

rather than:

```
if ( $chance40 )
    doSomething();
else if ( $chance30 )
    doSomethingElse();
else if ( $chance25 )
    return;
else if ( $chance5 )
    doSomethingElse2();
```

It's just nicer ordering by functionality...

EDIT2:

One size does not fit all. If your conditions are methods returning booleans, order them by how fast the method runs combined with the chance. I guess there's not really one good answer, you need to adapt. For example, if my $chance25 was replaced by a method `reallySlowMethodDoNotUseUnlessYouReallyHaveTo()`, I would surely check it last. :D

Comment: Thanks guys! I was thinking more of each if statement taking the same amount of time to run, as opposed to one taking 10 sec and the other 5 sec. But it looks like it doesn't really matter too much to speed, just readability. Thanks!

Comment: I know what you meant, my brain just sort of wandered off there for a second :D

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what @Luchian. Your primary focus should be readability of the code

You should profile your application before you optimize your code. How you order your condition is highly dependent on how much time is spent in "each if condition".

Let's take an example:

```
         Execution time - %ge called
Case 1 - 50 seconds (80% of time)
Case 2 - 10 seconds (15% of time)
Case 3 - 1 second    (5% of time)

100 runs:

Order A (In the order of "how often a condition is executed")
Case 1, Case 2, Case 3 = (80 * 50) + (15 * 60) + (5 * 61) = 5205 seconds

Order B (In the order of "execution times")
Case 3, Case 2, Case 1 = (5 * 1) + (15 * 11) + (80 * 61) = 5050 seconds
```

Comment: Why are you adding execution time of previous cases to below once. (Ex: In order A; execution time of "Case 2" count as 60 instead of 10 seconds). Each case doesn't have to wait for other cases to be execute, is it? If we don't consider execution time(switching time) between each case, then it should be correct as; Order A :: Case 1, Case 2, Case 3 = (80 * 50) + (15 * 10) + (5 * 1) and Order B :: Case 3, Case 2, Case 1 = (5 * 1) + (15 * 10) + (80 * 50). Correct me, if I don't understand what you said !.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is probably a web application (since this is most popular usage of PHP), so most of the time it waits for external resources like database, file access or webservices. Unless you're doing it in a loop that's executed thousands of times, or in a recursive method, it won't really matter which condition goes first. Strive for code that's easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your preference of operation

you might want condition two to activate rather than condition one and vice versa

```
$value=25;

if ($value > 20)
{
$value=200;
}
else if ($value < 50)
{
$value=5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply checking the value of `$conditions` against multiple possible text values, instead of doing `if/else`, use [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

```
switch ($conditions) {
    case "This is the most chosen condition":
        // do stuff
        break;
    case "This is the second most chosen condition":
        // do stuff
        break;
    case "This is the third most chosen condition":
        // do stuff
        break;
    default:
        // do stuff
}
```

If the most common condition is first, it will not have to evaluate any other cases and will therefore be faster, but the difference is going to be so extremely small that it really isn't going to matter one way or another. Usually you should go for readability over speed.

Comment: My understanding is you're incorrect in describing a `switch-case`. A `switch` will evaluate the value of the provided `$conditions`, and then uses a `jump table` to go to the correct `case` - it does not have to compare the `switch` value against each individual `case` value. Thus ordering of the cases has absolutely no impact on performance in a `switch-case`.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare that's not true. From the manual: "*The switch statement executes line by line (actually, statement by statement). In the beginning, no code is executed. Only when a case statement is found with a value that matches the value of the switch expression does PHP begin to execute the statements. PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements of the following case.*"

Comment: From your quote: "In the beginning, no code is executed. Only when a case statement is found with a value that matches the value of the switch expression does PHP begin to execute the statements." - Would not checking each case count as code being executed? It doesn't, thus no code is executed. They manage that behavior with a jump table. The significance of that paragraph is the fact that it will continue executing statements until it reaches a break or the end - it doesn't care if it goes over a case label because the compiled code has nothing between consecutive cases.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare interesting theory. I checked through the PHP source code, but couldn't see where `switch` was defined (I'm guessing they just use the native `C` version), so I had to put it to the test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/TQkW5x turns out I was right.

Comment: However it turns out I was wrong about `switch` being faster than `elseif` according to http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/PHP-Performance-Tuning-if-VS-switch/